# Ubuntu ko file not being built

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I just built and installed my custom Ubuntu kernel. Now, I'm looking to write and build my kernel driver as part of the kernel build process. At the moment, I build the kernel as `make -j$(nproc) bindeb-pkg` and install the kernel with `dpkg -i`.

My kernel driver is in the folder `drivers/mycustomdriver/`. The contents of `drivers/mycustomdriver/Makefile` is as follows

```
obj-$(CONFIG_MYCUSTOMDRIVER) += mycustomdriver.o
```

I also have a `drivers/mycustomdriver/Kconfig` that introduces the config `MYCUSTOMDRIVER`. `drivers/Kconfig` has been modified to source `drivers/mycustomdriver/Kconfig` and `drivers/Makefile` has the following :

```
obj-$(CONFIG_MYCUSTOMDRIVER) += mycustomdriver/
```

At this point when I build the kernel with the config set, I can see that `drivers/mycustomdriver/mycustomdriver.o` is created. However, I don't see a `mycustomdriver.ko` created.

What am I doing wrong? How can I ensure that my driver is built, signed and packaged within the deb file?

Comment: Probably you forgot to update kernel configuration. And FYI, much easier, and enormously faster, is to compile your custom module separately.

Comment: The .config used to compile the kernel does have CONFIG_MYCUSTOMDRIVER turned on. Which configuration are you referring to? (The reason I'm looking to integrate it into tree is that I'd like to maintain it in my local source tree going forward; and not have to bother with signing the driver separately etc).

Comment: When you reconfigured, did your default setting or selection lead to your CONFIG_ symbol being set to `y` or `m`?

Comment: Thank you, I just rechecked, it was set to `y`. I just changed it to `m`, hope that works.

Comment: Is your driver listing in make menuconfig ?